# how to install sbt without internet connection

Tags: sbt

I am trying to install sbt on our RedHat Linux server (RHEL6.8). The server doesn't have internet connection.
I downloaded sbt-1.0.x.zip from github but I don't see installation instruction. In README.md file, it points to http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup which tells me to use yum command. But that would require Internet connection.
Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: sbt 0.13.14 is coming out today-ish and has some support for offline installation. The documentation so far is this ticket: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2518

Comment: Thank you, Justin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt 0.13.15 [supports offline installation with a preloaded local repo](http://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-04-10-sbt-01315-JDK9-support-and-offline-installation/#offline-installation-with-preloaded-local-repo):

> sbt 0.13.15 adds two new repositories called “local-preloaded-ivy”
>   and “local-preloaded” that point to ~/.sbt/preloaded/.
>   The purpose for the repositories is to preload them with
>   sbt artifacts during the initial installation, instead of resolving
>   from the remote repository on the first run.
>   This enables installation of sbt without network connection.

To enable resolving of your own dependencies, it should be sufficient to add them to the preloaded directory.

Comment: That is great news! I will try it out. I have been stuck on this because no matter what I do it tries to go out and get things from the Internet.

Comment: I am sorry Justin, I am not familiar with how this works. I can't seem to find how to mark your answer as accepted. Can you please advise?

Comment: there should be a check mark right next to the vote button. have a look at this question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the RPM from bintray. See the instructions here:

Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

Depending on what dependencies are unfulfilled, you may need to download additional RPM files that sbt depends on.

Comment: Hi, Dan. The link you referred to instructs me to use "curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo" to get the rpm. But I can't access the internet from my server. I won't be able to run that command.

Comment: You'll have to download the .rpm file using an internet connected computer (you don't have to use curl, any web browser will do). After that, copy it across to the disconnected computer (USB drive or similar).

Comment: Hi, Dan. With that command, I only get a bintray-sbt-rpm.repo file that has the following content, <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html> by the way how do I put newline in my comment?

Comment: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-0.13.13.rpm is the file you want, not the repo file. Once you have that file, you'll want to Google "how to install rpm file" as it's beyond the scope of this question really.